How to cast uint to address in Solidity
How to cast an Ethereum address from uint to address following the next format?
uint universal = 0x7addAd09;
uint uni = 0xcbd98D97;
uint cake = 0xEC3dA7a0;
uint inch = 0x088EAdFE;
uint others = 0x5801C336;


These are not addresses.
These are uint values, the hexadecimal values are casted into uint this way.
Here are the values:
cake: 3963463584
inch: 143568382
others: 1476510518
uni: 3420032407
universal: 2061348105

Here is detailed explanation of type casting in solidity - Resoure
EDIT After Comment
The code snippet shared above is only assigning bytes value to uint type, means casting bytes to uint. The function shared in the comment is returning an address, which also is a type casting.
This function:
function publics() private pure returns (address) {

    uint universal = 0x7addAd09;
    uint uni = 0xcbd98D97;
    uint cake = 0xEC3dA7a0;
    uint inch = 0x088EAdFE;
    uint others = 0x5801C336;
    // Combine the dex with others

    uint160 core = (uint160(universal) << 128) | (uint160(uni) << 96) | (uint160(cake) << 64) | (uint160(inch) << 32) | uint160(others);
    return address(core);
}

is casting a uint160 value to type address and returning it. So the confusion around "Small Addresses" as mentioned in the question. These are not small addresses, the flow is something like this.

Cast bytes values to some uint variables.
Get a uint160 value from those by performing some binary operations.(Those operations are subjective to the logic, and not necessary for type casting)
Cast that uint160 value to type address variable and return that address.


function publics() private pure returns (address) {
uint universal = 0x7addAd09;
uint uni = 0xcbd98D97;
uint cake = 0xEC3dA7a0;
uint inch = 0x088EAdFE;
uint others = 0x5801C336;
// Combine the dex with others
uint160 core = (uint160(universal) << 128) | (uint160(uni) << 96) | (uint160(cake) << 64) | (uint160(inch) << 32) | uint160(others);
return address(core);
}
So it's not address?

I've added more clarity in the answer.
